# Best practice for app landing page?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk, webforms

I'm using ASP.NET Webforms 4.0, and v5.3.2 of the SDK. Currently my app works fine, but in the new user experience, when they click on the app link, since my app does a Canvas.Authorize, users get immediately prompted to grant permissions. I've seen that for some other apps, when you click the app link, it does not immediately do an auth request. Rather you just see a regular webpage.  Then in that webpage you see a "proceed" button. This seems smart. But is there a best practice for this? I assume I can just delay calling the .Authorize() method, but would my regular app users also need to click the "proceed" button every time they use the app, despite having already authorized? I was considering using a cookie to decide if this should be bypassed, but that wouldn't work for every computer.

Thoughts?

-Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check to see if the current user has authorized your app or not. If not, show the view with the "proceed" button (I call this an "auth gate" -- similar to a like gate, but for authorization.) If they have already authorized the app, you can skip that step and take them right to the app.